# Nginx doesn't execute php in specific directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

this is my nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen      90;
    server_name localhost;
    root        /var/www/wypok/;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        if ($request_uri = /) {
            return 301 /mirkoplusy;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteToMirkoplusy;
    }

    location @rewriteToMirkoplusy {
        return 301 /mirkoplusy;
    }

    location ~* /mirkoplusy {
        rewrite (?i)^/mirkoplusy/wpis/(.*)/(css|js|fonts)/(.+)/?$ /mirkoplusy/$2/$3;
        rewrite (?i)^/mirkoplusy/wpis/(.*)/?$ /mirkoplusy/;
    }

    location ~* /api {
        rewrite (?i)^/api/v(\d+)/(.+)/?$ /mirkoplusy/api/v$1/main.php?_url=/$2;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The problem is that php files are not executed under the api directory. When I connect to http://localhost:90/api/v2/init I get back the source code of my main.php file which is called by the rewrite rule

> location ~* /api {
>
> ```
>    rewrite (?i)^/api/v(\d+)/(.+)/?$ /mirkoplusy/api/v$1/main.php?_url=/$2;
> ```
>
> }

I created test.php file under the main root and it works so there must be some problem in that rewrite rule. Genreally I want every api call like /api/v2/entry/23224 to be passed to /api/v2/main.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
...
Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file.
...

---

I think that rewritten url is catched by `location ~* /mirkoplusy` and is not processed by `location ~ \.php$`.
Try to define locations `mirkoplusy` and `api` by prefix:

```
location /mirkoplusy {
    rewrite (?i)^/mirkoplusy/wpis/(.*)/(css|js|fonts)/(.+)/?$ /mirkoplusy/$2/$3;
    rewrite (?i)^/mirkoplusy/wpis/(.*)/?$ /mirkoplusy/;
}

location /api {
    rewrite (?i)^/api/v(\d+)/(.+)/?$ /mirkoplusy/api/v$1/main.php?_url=/$2;
}
```

Or add location `php` to `mirkoplusy`

```
location ~* /mirkoplusy {
    rewrite (?i)^/mirkoplusy/wpis/(.*)/(css|js|fonts)/(.+)/?$ /mirkoplusy/$2/$3;
    rewrite (?i)^/mirkoplusy/wpis/(.*)/?$ /mirkoplusy/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted the ~* chars from both rules and everything works, thank you.